# Unable to get the data from Ancestor Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following datagrids:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridWorkOrders" ItemsSource="{StaticResource workorders}"  Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Quantity" Binding="{Binding TotalQuantity}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>


  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Padding="10">
                        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>


  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Quantity"  Binding="{Binding Path=TotalQuantity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now inside rowdetails template I try to access TotalQuantity that is bound to parent datagrid row.  I tried achiving using ancestor but not working

**Edit**
Code for Model:

```
class WorkOrders : ObservableCollection<WorkOrder>
    {
        public WorkOrders()
        {
            var orderList = OrderDetailsProvider.GetOrders() as List<WorkOrder>;

            orderList.ForEach(
                        order => this.Add(order));
        }
    }

public class WorkOrder:BaseEntity
    {
        private string orderID;
        private int totalQuantity;
        private string status;
        private ObservableCollection<Schedule> scheduleCollection;

       ....All the fields exposed as proporties
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the code of the workorders resource please?

Comment: @FlorianGl, Updated wororders and WorkOrder code

Comment: Change `Path=TotalQuantity` to `Path=DataContext.TotalQuantity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a binding that finds the `DataGridRow` 2 levels up the tree.
The first one found is the one in the DataGrid in the `RowDetailsTemplate` (which we don't want) and the second one is the parent row of the current `RowDetailsTemplate`.

By binding to `DataContext.TotalQuantity` on the found `DataGridRow` you should get the value you are looking for.

So on the column in the details template you can do this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Quantity"
    Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.TotalQuantity, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow, AncestorLevel=2}}" />
```

Comment: It also works with `Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.TotalQuantity, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"` I think.

Comment: Yes, it would work, but also break much more easily. If he decided not to use a DataGrid at all in the details template or for some reason set a different DataContext on it in the future, it would not work any more. Also binding directly to the control that contains the value, is more intention revealing than using some middleman that happens to inherit the datacontext, imo.